Waterfall chart based on 2 columns on x-axis
I would like to create a waterfall chart based on two columns - Dept and Structure for each project. I would like to have 6 values on the x-axis and the cost on the y-axis. I have Structure as Category and Dept as Breakdown.



Project
Dept
Structure
Cost




Project A
HR
1
5000


Project A
HR
2
4500


Project A
HR
3
5500


Project A
PM
1
7000


Project A
PM
2
6000


Project A
PM
3
7500


Project A
Logistics
1
11500


Project A
Logistics
2
13000


Project A
Logistics
3
12000


Project A
Revenue
1
5500


Project A
Revenue
2
7000


Project A
Revenue
3
8000


Project A
Total costs
1
23500


Project A
Total costs
2
24500


Project A
Total costs
3
26000


Project B
HR
1
4500


Project B
HR
2
4000


Project B
HR
3
5000


Project B
PM
1
6000


Project B
PM
2
5000


Project B
PM
3
6500


Project B
Logistics
1
15000


Project B
Logistics
2
14000


Project B
Logistics
3
16000


Project B
Revenue
1
6000


Project B
Revenue
2
7000


Project B
Revenue
3
8000


Project B
Total costs
1
26500


Project B
Total costs
2
26500


Project B
Total costs
3
27000


Project C
HR
1
9000


Project C
HR
2
8500


Project C
HR
3
9500


Project C
PM
1
7500


Project C
PM
2
7000


Project C
PM
3
8000


Project C
Logistics
1
10500


Project C
Logistics
2
11000


Project C
Logistics
3
10000


Project C
Revenue
1
7000


Project C
Revenue
2
8000


Project C
Revenue
3
9000


Project C
Total costs
1
27000


Project C
Total costs
2
28000


Project C
Total costs
3
29500


Project D
HR
1
7500


Project D
HR
2
7000


Project D
HR
3
8000


Project D
PM
1
5000


Project D
PM
2
4500


Project D
PM
3
6000


Project D
Logistics
1
12000


Project D
Logistics
2
11000


Project D
Logistics
3
13000


Project D
Revenue
1
6000


Project D
Revenue
2
6500


Project D
Revenue
3
7000


Project D
Total costs
1
24500


Project D
Total costs
2
25000


Project D
Total costs
3
26000


Project E
HR
1
8000


Project E
HR
2
7500


Project E
HR
3
8500


Project E
PM
1
5500


Project E
PM
2
5000


Project E
PM
3
6500


Project E
Logistics
1
14000


Project E
Logistics
2
13000


Project E
Logistics
3
15000


Project E
Revenue
1
7000


Project E
Revenue
2
7500


Project E
Revenue
3
8000


Project E
Total costs
1
27500


Project E
Total costs
2
28000


Project E
Total costs
3
29000



What I tried I tried to create this measure but it doesn't work.
Var Dev1 = [REV1] - [Cost1]
Var Dev2 = [REV2] - [Cost2]
Var Dev3 = [REV3] - [Cost3]
Var Devtotal = CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[ Cost]), all(Sheet1[ Dept]))
RETURN
Dev1 + Dev2 + Devtotal + Dev3 


What I am expecting
1 = Revenue at Structure 1 - Total costs at Structure 1 
2 = Revenue at Structure 2 - Total costs at Structure 2 
HR = HR at Structure 2 - HR at Structure 3 
PM = PM at Structure 2 - PM at Structure 3 
Logistics = Logistics at Structure 2 - Logistics at Structure 3 
3 = Revenue at Structure 3 - Total costs at Structure 3


Issues

The values at Structure 1, 2 & 3 are incorrect
I also don't want the values of Dept to be displayed between Structure 1 & 2.

Please how do I achieve this?
Thank you.
